# Search a list of polygons for that which contains a particular point

Tags: list-manipulation, regions

I have a list of regions and want to find which of those regions a certain point belongs to. My best attempt works, but only after throwing an error:

```
list = {Rectangle[{0, 0}], Rectangle[{1, 0}], Rectangle[{2, 0}]};
Position[list, _?(RegionMember[#, {3, 0}] &), {1}]
(*RegionMember::A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of RegionMember[List,{3,0}].*)
(*{{3}}*)
```

It also seems to work surprisingly slowly on a real use case, and I'm wondering if this is because of the error. Note that I ideally do need the actual position, so using `Pick[]` probably won't help. In my particular usage, only one of the polygons in the list will contain the point in question. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Position[RegionMember[#, {3, 0}] & /@ list, True]
```

> {{3}}

Comment: Beauty! Thanks!